# How to write this symbol in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

I have this equation-->

[image]

There is a T like symbol, what is it called and how to write that in latex?

Comment: Do you mean Γ? It's `\Gamma`.

Comment: This [webpage](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) might be interesting for seeing some of the TeX symbols.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad Great Link buddy. Thank you. :)